# average times data matches each columns

Tags: r

I am trying to find the average number of instances which match in R.

I want to know when all 3 columns == 1 and when all 3 columns == 0 and finally for both.

This does not work:

```
mean(test$direction == test$pred.lm == test$pred.svm)
```

This gives me the total instances the `direction` column equals the `pred.lm` column.

```
mean(test$direction == test$pred.lm)
```

Example:

```
           direction pred.lm pred.svm
2018-07-20         0       0        0
2018-07-23         1       0        0
2018-07-24         0       0        1
2018-07-25         1       1        1
2018-07-26         1       1        1
2018-07-27         0       0        0
```

Here row 1, row 4, 5 and row 6 all match. I want the average number of times they match when == 0 and also == 1 and finally all matches, regardless of 0 or 1.

Data:

```
library(xts)
df <- structure(c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), index = structure(c(1532044800, 
    1532304000, 1532390400, 1532476800, 1532563200, 1532649600, 1532908800, 
    1532995200, 1533081600, 1533168000, 1533254400, 1533513600, 1533600000, 
    1533686400, 1533772800, 1533859200, 1534118400, 1534204800, 1534291200, 
    1534377600, 1534464000, 1534723200, 1534809600, 1534896000, 1534982400, 
    1535068800, 1535328000, 1535414400, 1535500800, 1535587200, 1535673600, 
    1536019200, 1536105600, 1536192000, 1536278400, 1536537600, 1536624000, 
    1536710400, 1536796800, 1536883200, 1537142400, 1537228800, 1537315200, 
    1537401600, 1537488000, 1537747200, 1537833600, 1537920000, 1538006400, 
    1538092800, 1538352000, 1538438400, 1538524800, 1538611200, 1538697600, 
    1538956800, 1539043200, 1539129600, 1539216000, 1539302400, 1539561600, 
    1539648000, 1539734400, 1539820800, 1539907200, 1540166400, 1540252800, 
    1540339200, 1540425600, 1540512000, 1540771200, 1540857600, 1540944000, 
    1541030400, 1541116800, 1541376000, 1541462400, 1541548800, 1541635200, 
    1541721600, 1541980800, 1542067200, 1542153600, 1542240000, 1542326400, 
    1542585600, 1542672000, 1542758400, 1542931200, 1543190400, 1543276800, 
    1543363200, 1543449600, 1543536000), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
    "zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC", src = "yahoo", updated = structure(1544903554.77594, class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(94L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("direction", 
    "pred.lm", "pred.svm")))
```

Comment: Can you make your sample data match your example?

Comment: It should be the same data. I took the head from the `dput` data. What is different for you?

Comment: Ah, it's an `xts` object, that's why it didn't show properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close; the main issue is that all the comparisons have to be binary, as in:

```
# All 1's
with(df, mean(direction == pred.lm & pred.lm == pred.svm & pred.svm == 1))
# [1] 0.1276596

# All 0's
with(df, mean(direction == pred.lm & pred.lm == pred.svm & pred.svm == 0))
# [1] 0.393617

# All equal
with(df, mean(direction == pred.lm & pred.lm == pred.svm))
# [1] 0.5212766
```

However, you may do something even better:

```
# All 1's
mean(rowSums(df) == ncol(df))
# [1] 0.1276596

# All 0's
mean(rowSums(df) == 0)
# [1] 0.393617

# All equal
mean(rowSums(df) %in% c(0, ncol(df)))
# [1] 0.5212766
```

That's not only shorter but also allows for more than three columns in `df`.

Answer (score 1):

What i got here from your question is that you want the mean of all the rows whose instances are either 0,0,0 or 1,1,1

```
> rowno.<-NULL
> for(i in 1:nrow(df))
+ if(all(df[i,]==0) || all(df[i,]==1))
+ rowno.<-c(rowno.,i)
> rowno.
[1]  1  4  5  6  7  8  9 11 12 17 19 20 21 23 25 31 32 33
[19] 34 36 38 39 45 48 51 53 54 55 56 57 58 65 68 69 71 73
[37] 74 75 77 78 80 82 83 86 89 91 92 93 94
> mean(rowno.)
[1] 47.91837
```

And if you want mean of all the observations ,you can get it by

```
     > mean(df[rowno.,])
     [1] 0.244898
```